# CDC class vid:pid to use for my STM32F3 based equipment

Tags: linux, windows, usb, stm32, cdc

I am plannig to use usb connection to let PC communicate with my equipment based on STM32F373VC.
I tried the CDC class using the example in STM32CubeF3 V1.9.0 by removing the uart peripheral management.
PC detects a usb device with vid:pid 0483:5740. Linux automatically recognizes CDC class (STMicroelectronics STM32F407), loads the cdc_acm module, and the ttyACM0 VCP is created. I don't know about Windows, but reading the readme of the example it seems that a driver should be installed.
I have some questions:

1. Can I use VID:PID 0483:5740 for my product?
2. Does the various versions of Windows automatically recognize the device (and associate it with the CDC driver) or is it really necessary to install a driver?
3. If I can't use these VID:PID, can I ask ST for a PID assigned to me for small productions (as other silicon vendors do)?
4. Could ST assign me a PID that the various versions of Windows, Linux and Mac automatically recognize as CDCs without needing to install drivers or configure anything?
5. If not, do VID:PID pairs exist that are automatically recognized by the various versions of Windows, Linux and Mac as CDC class without needing to install drivers or configure and that I can legally use for my small production?

Answer (score 1):

**About drivers recognizing your device:**

If your device is of class CDC, driver should be able to be loaded no matter what VID:PID is used (as long as selected VID:PID is not assigned to other device that has device specific driver). For Windows please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820(v=vs.85).aspx) document.
You should be able to test Linux CDC class driver by altering device descriptor in your device library code (which should be possible, if I correctly understand available ST documentation).

**About having your own VID:PID:**

There is some thread on github about this [here](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/47). It should cover all possible options including the ones you asked about.